# Session Facade versus Facade??? any difference? or same thing?

Tags: spring, facade

Is there any difference between Facade pattern and session facade pattern? how can we implement session facade pattern using spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

A session facade is basically an EJB session bean which acts as a facade to other components and beans within an EJB application. ie behaviourally it is a just a standard facade.